# Complete Supervisor Hierarchy for an employee SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can we print entire employee hierarchy for each employee using oracle SQL hierarchial query.

Sample Employee Table>>

```
EmpID, ENAME, MGR
1,     A,     1
2,     B,     1
3,     C,     2
4,     C,     2
5,     C,     3
```

Sample Output>>

```
EmpID, ENAME, Hierarchy
1,     A,     -
2,     B,     /1
3,     C,     /1/2
4,     C,     /1/2
5,     C,     /1/2/3
```

Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a database to test this out on, but thinking you need to use `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` and `CONNECT BY PRIOR`. Try something like:

```
SELECT EmpID, ENAME, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(MGR, '/') "Heirarchy"
FROM Employee
CONNECT BY PRIOR EmpID= MGR;
```

Comment: You should also add a start with clause `start with empid = mgr` and change the *connect by* clause to `CONNECT BY PRIOR EmpID= MGR and empId != mgr`. Still, the result will not be exactly what the OP wants, but it's close.

Comment: Thanks Joe's for your response., Somehow its not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *common table expression* (CTE):

*Test Data*:

```
create table tq84_sample_employee (
  empid  number  primary key,
  ename  varchar2(10),
  mgr    number references tq84_sample_employee
);

insert into tq84_sample_employee values(1, 'A', 1);
insert into tq84_sample_employee values(2, 'B', 1);
insert into tq84_sample_employee values(3, 'C', 2);
insert into tq84_sample_employee values(4, 'C', 2);
insert into tq84_sample_employee values(5, 'C', 3);
```

*Select Statement with a CTE*:

```
with e(empId, ename, hierarchy) as (
  select
    t.empId,
    t.ename,
    null
  from
    tq84_sample_employee t
  where
    empId = mgr
                     UNION ALL
  select
    t.empId,
    t.ename,
    e.hierarchy || '/' || e.empId
  from
    tq84_sample_employee t join
    e                    e on t.mgr = e.empId
  where
    t.empId != t.mgr
)
select 
  empId,
  ename,
  nvl(hierarchy, '-') hierarchy
from e;
```

*Cleaning up*

```
drop table tq84_sample_employee;
```

Note, I'd set the `mgr` for `empId=1` to `null` because technically, someone is not his own manager. The top most person in a hierarchy doesn't have a manager so it's technically more correct to accordingly set the manager. This will also make an according statement easier.

Comment: Thanks Rene, for suggestion, Lemme try and will let you know